# 'hook' types out of anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to 'get' a class/function/variable that's declared inside a function? example:

```js
  () => {
       class foo{

        }
        
        const bar = () =>
        {
            console.log("Can print from outside?")
        }
    }
    
    //Any way to make this possible?:
    console.log(new foo())
    bar()
```

Note: Can't change the anonymous function (injection related)

Comment: There's no way to access locally declared variables in that function outside of the function.

Comment: And: why would you put a class inside a function?

Comment: The best you can do is to return the class. But it is not a good practice, as mantioned.

Answer (score 1):

JS is lexical scope, you can't access a local variable outside its function.
you may wanna check **Closures**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky!!, but if you don't mind another instance of the code you can just get the current source and wrap inside a function that exposes the foo & bar..

eg..

```js
const anom = () => {
  class foo{
  }
  const bar = () =>
  {
     console.log("Can print from outside?")
  }
}

let code = anom.toString();
code = 
  code.slice(
    code.indexOf('{') + 1,
    code.lastIndexOf('}')
  ) + 'return {foo, bar}';

const f = new Function(code);

const {foo, bar} = f();

bar();
var fooInst = new foo();

console.log(fooInst);
```